# Java for Selenium - String comparison

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am facing an issue in if statement for below code.
I am not able to log into if statement even with correct condition. Is my syntax correct?

```
String NicotineProduct="Not in the last 5 years"

if (NicotineProduct=="No, Never"||NicotineProduct=="Not in the last 5 years"||NicotineProduct=="Not in the last 3 years")
 {    
    if (rateclass=="Pref Best No Nicotine")
             rateclassval=1;
    else if (rateclass=="Pref No Nicotine")
           rateclassval=2;
    else if (rateclass=="Select No Nicotine")
           rateclassval=3;
    else if (rateclass=="Standard No Nicotine")
           rateclassval=4;
 }
```

Comment: No, your syntax is not correct in that it does not bare the semantics you want. Always use [String.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for String comparisons; everything else means asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `.equals` for `String` comparisons:

```
if (NicotineProduct.equals("No, Never")||NicotineProduct.equals("Not in the last 5 years")||NicotineProduct.equals("Not in the last 3 years")) {
    if (rateclass.equals("Pref Best No Nicotine"))
         rateclassval=1;
    else if (rateclass.equals("Pref No Nicotine"))
         rateclassval=2;
    else if (rateclass.equals("Select No Nicotine"))
         rateclassval=3;
    else if (rateclass.equals("Standard No Nicotine"))
         rateclassval=4;
}
```

See this other question/answer:

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

String.equals() is the preferred way for comparing string values.